# How to clean a baby's mouth from Gentian Violet?

Tags: infant, cleaning

Does anyone know of any way to get Gentian Violet off of a baby's mouth/lips? We have to give him 2 more doses I believe and he is already a purple mess after the first dose. I realize that the mouth, teeth and tongue are going to be stained. But surely there is a way to remove some of it from all over his mouth?

Comment: Have you tried mild lemon juice or Orange juice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently rubbing alcohol or vodka on a cotton swab will remove some of the staining. You can prevent or at least reduce the staining by using some vaseline or olive oil on your babies lips before using the Gentian Violet.

Here a link with [tips for removing Gentian Violet stains](http://breastfeeding.hypermart.net/gvstains.html).

Comment: I've asked a relative who uses a similar fluid in the ear, how she prevents the stains in the first place. **Vaseline** was her answer too! I wanted to post this as an answer, but you beat me to it -- with a link, even :-)

Comment: I would avoid getting rubbing alcohol anywhere near babies mouth. High percentage alcohol can do terrible damage to gums.